# Functions which map $w_n : S^n\to Z, w_n(x) =$ the number of $1$'s in $x$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

[image: Question]

So, I'm having trouble understanding exactly what this function is mapping onto what.
Does it map $S$, which can be either $1$ or $0$, raised to the power of $n$ to an integer?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$S^n=S\times S\times S...\times S$ where the cartesian product is taken $n$ times. Hence $S^n:=\{(a_1,a_2,...,a_n):a_i\in S=\{0,1\}~\forall i\}$, is the set of $n-$bit strings (bit strings of length $n$). $w_n$ maps each bit string to the number of $1$s it contains. The domain of $w_n$ is $S^n$ and the codomain is the set of integers. The range is $\Bbb Z_{\ge0}$.

Comment: thanks that literally cleared everything up

Comment: If you are satisfied with this answer, consider accepting it by clicking the tick mark button. @shawks5088